# Excel - VBA | Make Chart Show Specific Series Depending On Which Button The User Clicks

Tags: vba, excel

I am a new user of Excel-VBA. So, i am attempting a small project to teach myself the baby steps. I wish to create an interactive chart that displays the curves of sin (x), cos (x), or tan (x) depending on which button the user clicks on the userform that I have created.

Below is VBA code for Module 1. This code creates the chart, positions the chart in the worksheet, generates the x-values, and generates the y values for the sin (x) set. I have only created the y values for the sin (x) set so far because I am more concerned with getting the userform buttons to do what I want them to do. Also, I wanted to hurry and post this question!

```
Option Explicit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub one()

'VARIABLES
Dim Row As Integer
Dim j As Single
Dim pi As Single
pi = 3.14159265359

'LABEL X SET
Cells(1, 38).Value = "X"

'GENERATE X VALUES
j = -4 * pi
For Row = 2 To 82

Cells(Row, 38).Value = j

j = j + 0.025 * pi

Next Row

'LABEL / GENERATE Y VALUES = SIN ( X )
Cells(1, 39).Value = "SIN ( X )"
For Row = 2 To 82

Cells(Row, 39).Value = Sin(Cells(Row, 38).Value)

Next Row

'CREATE CHART 1
Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set c = c.Location(where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")
With c
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    .Legend.Delete
End With

'POSITION CHART 1
Dim cobject As ChartObject
Dim r As Range
Set cobject = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(37, 22))
cobject.Left = r.Left
cobject.Top = r.Top
cobject.Width = r.Width
cobject.Height = r.Height

'DISPLAY USERFORM 1
Userform1.Show


End Sub
```

The simple userform I have created has three command buttons. Button 1 for Sin (x), Button 2 for Cos (x), and Button 3 for Tan (x).
Below is the code I have written for Button1_Click. It is not a part of module one. It is under its own section in the project explorer. VBAProject/Forms/Userform1

```
Option Explicit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sinx As Series
Set sinx = c.SeriesCollection.NewSeries :::ERROR
With sinx
    .Values = Range(Cells(2, 39), Cells(82, 39))
    .XValues = Range(Cells(2, 38), Cells(82, 38))
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbBlack
    c.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 2
End With

End Sub
```

So... I run Module 1. It successfully generates the x values to their respective range, generates the sin (x) values to their respective range, creates and positions the chart, and displays UserForm1. HOWEVER! When I click Button 1 on the userform, I get an error...

Compile Error:
Variable Not Defined

Excel kindly highlights the line of code which causes the error.
I have denoted this line of code with :::ERROR
I assume that the error is referring to "c" which I have defined as a chart in module 1. I guess that the defined variables do not transfer from module 1 to the userform1.

My objective is for the user to be able to click sin (x) a.k.a button 1 or cos (x) button 2 or tan (x) button 3 on the userform and then either the curve of sin, cos, or tan would should up on the chart.
I thank in advance all members of stackoverflow that comment towards this inquiry. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discovering (with the error you highlighted) that VBA variables have *scope*: they are known only to the module in which they are declared, unless you declare them to be **public** (at the module level) in the module in which you declare them.
, and again in another module in which you use them.  See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843144/en-us) for more details.

Back to your question: declare

```
Option Explicit
Public c as Chart
```

at the module level (before Sub one()) in Module 1; remove the corresponding

```
Dim c as Chart
```

from inside `Sub one()`.  Next, change the code for the userform as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sinx As Series

Set sinx = c.SeriesCollection.Add(Source:=Range(Cells(2, 38), Cells(82, 39)), _
  CategoryLabels:=True)

With sinx
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbBlack
    c.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 2
End With

' important: must hide the dialog so control returns to the calling sub!
Me.Hide

End Sub
```

These changes made things work for me...

Comment: Floris. Thank you very much for the quick response. I have added "Public c As Chart" just below where it says "Option Explicit" in both the userform code and module 1 code. So.. I run Module 1 and click button_1. The error I receive... Run-time error 91: Object Variable or With Block Variable not set. My question is now.. where should i declare "Public c as Chart" to make this work? Or what am I not including that I should be?

Comment: Updated the answer... let me know if this fixed it for you.

Comment: Floris. Yes, you have completely answered my question and allowed me to achieve my goal. I very much appreciate this. Sorry I did not write this sooner. I have been away from internet access. If I had the reputation points I would +1 your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! You can still "accept" the answer (little check mark)... even with low reputation.

Comment: I accepted the answer and HEY! I got 2 reputation points just for doing that. I do have one more question. I am new to StackOverflow so I am unaware of the rules and regulations of this site. If I wanted to post my new code on this thread and ask another question about it, would it be acceptable to "answer" my own question and post the code and question in the "answer"? Or is it more common to edit my original question? Thanks for all the help.